# Maximising largest integer on a list given mean, median and mode

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, optimization

A list of $10$ positive integers has a mean of $11$, a median of $10$ and a unique mode of $7$. What is the largest possible value of an integer in the list?

In an ascending (albeit not strictly ascending) list of ten positive integers ($n_1$ to $n_{10}$), the last will be the highest, and you want to make the earlier ones as small as possible. The given conditions force $\sum_{i=1}^{10}n_i = 110$ and $n_5 + n_6 = 20$. In addition, at least two values have to be $7$.

With a bit of trial and error I deduced the optimal list is probably $1, 2, 7, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 34$ with the answer being $34$. But I'm dissatisfied with this as I can't be sure it's the best solution and I'm wondering if there's a more systematic way of approaching the problem (short of an exhaustive search).

Thank you.

Comment: $1,7,7,7,10,10,11,11,12,34$ also works.

Comment: @Yorch Thanks, if memory serves, I also found that solution (doesn't change the maximum value of course). Two great answers so far. I'll look through them carefully and decide on which to accept (I've already upvoted both).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition $n_5 + n_6 = 20$ implies that $n_5 \le 10 \le n_6$, from which we deduce that the value $7$ occurs at least twice and at most five times, all of which must precede $n_6$.

From this, we consider two cases:  first, when $n_5 = 7$, and second, when $n_5 > 7$.  The case $n_5 < 7$ is impossible since we require $n_6 \ge 10$.

**Case 1:** $(n_5 = 7)$
This implies $n_6 = 13$, hence $13 \le n_7 \le n_8 \le n_9 \le n_{10}$.  Since the goal is to maximize $n_{10}$ for a fixed total $T = 110$, we must minimize the other values of $n_i$; i.e., $n_{i+1} \in \{n_i, n_i + 1\}$ for each $i = 6, 7, 8$.  Consequently $n_9$ is at least $13$ and at most $16$.

On the other end, we must also have at least $n_4 = 7$, and $1 \le n_1 \le n_2 \le n_3 \le 7$.  If we have $n_3 < 7$, then all other $n_i$ are unique and this forces the choice
$$(1, 2, 3, 7, 7, 13, 14, 15, 16, 32).$$
If we have $n_3 = 7$, this is only slightly better since the minimal choice becomes
$$(1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 13, 13, 14, 14, 33).$$
Increasing the frequency of $7$ saved $1$ from the low end and $4$ on the high end but cost $4$ by changing $n_3 = 3$ to $n_3 = 7$.  It is obvious that allowing $n_2 = 7$ or $n_1 = 7$ will be inferior to the above, since at most $2$ more units can be saved from the high end but at a minimum cost of $6$ on the low.  Therefore the maximum $n_{10}$ attained in this case is $33$.

**Case 2:** $(n_5 > 7)$
We must have at least two of $n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4$ equal to $7$, and $n_5 \in \{8, 9, 10\}$.  If exactly two of the $n_i$ equal $7$, then $n_5 \ne 10$, and the minimum is attained for the choices $(1, 2, 7, 7, n_5, 20 - n_5, 21 - n_5, 22 - n_5, 23 - n_5, 7 + 3n_5)$; thus the choice $n_5 = 9$ gives $n_{10} = 34$, with the sequence $$(1, 2, 7, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 34).$$

If more than two of the $n_i$ equal $7$, then we may choose $n_5 = 10$, and we have for example $$(1, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 34)$$ for three repetitions, and $$(7, 7, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 30)$$ for four repetitions, which is inferior.

Therefore, the maximum is $n_{10} = 34$, attained for exactly those two sequences described above.

Comment: Thank you very much. And thanks for editing that $32$ to $33$, I was wondering if I had misunderstood you at first.

Comment: Very systematic and rigorous. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We wish to minimize the sum of the other $9$ numbers $a_1\leq \dots \leq a_9$ with the condition $a_5+a_6 = 20$ and the condition that $7$ appears more times than the others, the sum we got is $76$, lets prove less is not possible.

If $a_5$ is $7$ then $a_6$ is $13$ and so $a_6+a_7+a_8+ a_9 \geq 4\times 13 = 52$, so the sum of $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_5$ would have to be less than  $24$. If $a_3,a_4,a_5= 7$ the minimum sum of $a_1+\dots + a_5$ is $1+1+7+7+7 = 23$ but since we can't have all of $a_6,\dots,a_{9} = 13$ this becomes impossible. Hence we must have $a_3\neq 7$ and the minimum is greedily $1+2+3+7+7+13+14+15+16 = 78$.

Hence $a_5> 7$. It can now be seen that if we select how many $7$'s we want then the solution can be formed greedily by taking the smallest numbers possible and setting $a_4 = 7$.

If there are two $7$'s the solution is $1,2,7,7,9,10,11,12,13=76$

If there are three $7$'s the solution is $1,7,7,7,10,10,11,11,12 = 76$

If there are four $7$'s the solution is $7,7,7,7,10,10,10,11,11 = 80$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure ${}{}$

Comment: Thanks again. I just want to understand your method completely. Is $a_6+a_7+a_8+ a_9 + a_{10} \geq 4\times 13 = 52$ supposed to read $a_6+a_7+a_8+ a_9  \geq 4\times 13 = 52$?

Comment: yes indeed ! ${}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. :)